# Upgrade button is missing from Ubuntu Software when opening .deb file in Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: package-management, 20.04, software-center, debian-installer

My current version of F5 SSL VPN is 7183 ([see here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qfo0j.png)), then I downloaded the update (version 7184) debian file, and when I open the .deb file, it leads to Ubuntu Software ([here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JQdBw.png)) and nothing's wrong up until this point, except that `Update` (or `Upgrade`, you get the idea) button is missing, only `Remove` button remains there.

Since I upgraded my workstation to Ubuntu 20.04, I can't upgrade via .deb file anymore.

It's making things tricky, especially for software/app you installed without using apt.

I know we can add the source to PPA so we don't need .deb anymore (included in `apt update` and `apt upgrade` instead) but it's too painful to register each of them to PPA, and I just want to use this deb file I download from internet every time they got an update (like dbeaver-ce).

Is it new "feature", expected, or bug (only found on Ubuntu 20.04) ?

How to upgrade this way (without using PPA) ? Remove and install them using newly deb file everytime I download new deb file?

Comment: I find the easiest way is to just use `gdebi`. It's a fine GUI for installing .deb files. Just open the .deb with it and click on install and it'll overwrite the existing version. It also will have a handy uninstall button if you've already installed the file from a .deb file. `sudo apt install gdebi` and be done with it.

Comment: Thank you @KGII I've seen that in other threads, it seems promising (even it's still annoying), if we really can't bring those upgrade button back, Imma resort to this, thank you sir.

Comment: I have the same issue , @Johnsons did you find any solution yet?

Comment: @eshirvana I'm doing `sudo dpkg -i <new version of .deb file>` now hehe...I don't know whether my original question really hab an answer (regarding that update button)..

Comment: @Johnsons yes , that works in terminal , however I was wondering what happened to the upgrade button , it was convenient to just click on upgrade button and update an app. now by UI I have to unistall app then install it again using new version

Comment: yess exactly that is what i was complaining about @eshirvana ...but i guess i couldn't care less anymore..as long as it works...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An equivalent of that action would be using `dpkg` command

```
sudo dpkg -i <your .deb file>
```

It will install and/or update (if it's existing) the software to your machine.

Comment: It works, but why do they have to make things more complicated as it is :)